# Convert List<String> to Map<String, List<String>> with list value as map key and map value with empty list java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

This could be a stupid question. I need to convert a `List<String>` to a `Map<String, List<String>>` with Java 8. All the list values `("20", "42", "55")` should be the key to the creating map while the value attribute of the creating map should be an empty list.

Although the following code does the task, it saves the list value as both map key and 1st index of the map value.

**How to resolve this using Java 8 features ??**

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("20", "42", "55");

Map<String, List<String>> serviceMap =
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Arrays::asList));
```

Comment: And just for the record: you understand that the map eliminates potential duplicate entries in your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `Arrays::asList` as the value mapper means that the value of each key would be a `List` that contains that key as its single element, but you said you want the value should be an empty `List`.

If the value should be a modifiable empty `List`, you should create a new `ArrayList` as the value of the `Map`:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("20", "42", "55");

Map<String, List<String>> serviceMap =
            list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), a -> new ArrayList<>()));
```

Comment: @SameeraManorathna this is Java 8

Comment: @Eran I do not think OP knows what he means/needs ;)

Comment: This will cause an exception if the list contains duplicates.

Comment: @Oleksandr that's true

Comment: Since nobody said, it has to be a mutable list, `Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> Collections.emptyList())` would do as well…

Comment: @Holger I assumed it should be mutable, since otherwise it seems pointless (why map these keys to empty lists (or any lists containing the exact same elements) if you can't modify these lists?)

Comment: Even with mutable lists, the task looks pointless to me. If a fixed set of keys is to be maintained, an `enum` + `EnumMap` would make more sense, otherwise, if the keys are not fixed, populating the map when actual elements are added, would be more reasonable. But it looks more like an academic example assignment, which needs “to be done in Java 8” more than anything else, and using immutable lists would be fine then or even preferable from that academic point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over each String in the list and add it as the map key, putting a new ArrayList as the value, like so:

```java
Map<String, List<String> result = Arrays.asList("20", "42", "55").stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), a -> new ArrayList<String>()));
```

Comment: @SameeraManorathna What is that supposed to mean? Streams were added with Java 8?!

Comment: I just updated my answer a minute ago; before it used a for loop. Sorry for the confusion!